# Mandar todos los nombres de imágenes pertenecientes a un mismo producto a distinta tabla en MySQL

Tags: mysql, woocommerce

Tengo 2 tablas:

Product_images (creada a partir de la importacion de un archivo *.csv*).

```
product_reference | name

REF.001           | example_image_1.jpg   
REF.001           | example_image_2.jpg
```

Importer* (creada para guardar los datos que necesito de otras tablas).

```
sku     | images

REF.001 | null
```

¿Cómo podría actualizar **Importer** para que quedase de la siguiente forma?

```
sku     | images

REF.001 | example_image_1.jpg,example_image_2.jpg
```

*Los datos de la tabla Importer serian para exportar en .csv y poder importarlos a WooComerce, de ahí que necesite importar las imágenes de la forma mencionada.

Answer (score 0):

Juanjo, como te comentaba ayer, puedes hacerlo partiendo de tu tabla `Product_images` directamente.

Te mostraré tres posibilidades, te puedes quedar con la que más te convenga.

### 1. Creando un archivo .csv directamente sin necesidad de tener una tabla `Importer`

La consulta sería:

```
$sql="SELECT product_reference, GROUP_CONCAT(name) images
      FROM Product_images 
      WHERE product_reference='REF.001' 
      GROUP BY product_reference";
```

Dependiendo de cómo manejes los datos obtenidos, sería cuestión de guardarlos en un array y luego crear el CSV, más o menos así:

```
$fp = fopen('import.csv', 'w');

foreach ($arrDatos as $val) {
    fputcsv($fp, $val);
}
fclose($fp);
```

El código de más arriba creará un archivo llamado `import.csv` en la ruta especificada, la cual puede cambiar.

`$arrDatos` sería un array más o menos así, con los resultados de la consulta:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_reference] => REF.001
            [images] => example_image_1.jpg,example_image_2.jpg
        )

)
```

Y el contenido de `import.csv` sería este:

```
REF.001,"example_image_1.jpg,example_image_2.jpg"
```

Otras opciones son posibles, como crear el archivo con encabezados, etc.

---

### 2. Llenando la tabla `Importer` a partir de una consulta de a la tabla `Product_images`

Esta posibilidad se parece a lo que tienes implementado ahora. Se trataría de usar la misma consulta de antes, y partiendo de ella, llenar los datos en `Importer`:

```
INSERT INTO Importer 
    (product_reference, images) 
    SELECT 
        product_reference, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(name) images
    FROM Product_images 
    WHERE product_reference='REF.001' 
    GROUP BY product_reference;
```

Esta consulta insertará esta fila en `Importer`:

```
product_reference | images

REF.001           | example_image_1.jpg,example_image_2.jpg
```

---

### 3. Creando un archivo a partir de la consulta desde el manejador de BD

Una posibilidad parecida a la número 1, para ejecutar directamente en el manejador. Para esto se requieren privilegios de archivo en el usuario que ejecuta la consulta. Dejo esta posibilidad en caso de que no estés trabajando con PHP.

```
SELECT 
    product_reference, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(name) images
FROM Product_images 
WHERE product_reference='REF.001' 
GROUP BY product_reference    
    INTO OUTFILE 'import.csv' 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

---

De cualquiera de estas tres formas podrías tener la tabla, o el archivo, con los datos que necesitas.

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Lo acabo de solucionar. Muchas gracias de todas formas por tu ayuda.

Comment: @JuanjoNC sería bueno que comentes la solución, para que pueda servir a otros. Esta red es también para utilidad de otros que en un futuro puedan experimentar el mismo problema.

Comment: Hecho. Estaba en ello.

Comment: Bien, me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto @JuanjoNC.

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucioné con esta expresión:

```
UPDATE importer 
JOIN (
    SELECT product_reference, GROUP_CONCAT(name) AS name
    FROM Product_images 
    GROUP BY product_reference
) pi ON importer.sku = pi.product_reference
SET importer.images = pi.name;
```